# How can i convert a SQL query into LINQ using group and having?

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, sum

I can properly execute the query in SQL Server Management Studio, but only for test purposes, I need to convert it to C# and Linq. I've seen some examples but none of them work, fails on the select.

I'm trying to select an Id which is result from a SUM of values in another table, a many-to-many table is in the middle, probably I'm doing wrong the join or at least it's what I think, could anyone help me?

This works fine..

```
select 
    ti.id_totalingresos
from 
    TotalIngresos ti, ParcialTotal pt, IngresosParciales ip
where 
    ti.id_totalingresos = pt.idtotales_FK and
    pt.idparciales_FK = ip.id_ingresosparciales and
    ip.periodo = 6 
group by 
    ti.id_totalingresos
having 
    SUM(ip.monto) = 5249866
```

And here's what I'm trying..

```
var query =
            from ti in bd.TotalIngresos
            join ip in bd.IngresosParciales on ti.IngresosParciales equals ip.TotalIngresos
            group ti by ti.IngresosParciales into x
            where x.Sum(x => x.monto) == total
            select x.Key; // <---??
```

Comment: In sql query you are grouping on one column and in linq on another....

Comment: I just updated the code.. Now i have an error : "The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect."

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to test it locally but does this work? Basically we need to flatten out the grouping to select an item...Forgot to mention...you will lose the grouping though if you flatten out...

```
var query =
        (
            from ti in bd.TotalIngresos
            join ip in bd.IngresosParciales on ti.IngresosParciales equals ip.TotalIngresos
            group ti by ti.IngresosParciales into x
            where x.Sum(x => x.monto) == total
            select x
        ).SelectMany (x => x)
        .Select (x => x.id_totalingresos);
```

Comment: I dont get why im getting this: "The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect."

Comment: check the data types may be :  ti.IngresosParciales equals ip.TotalIngresos

Comment: I did this but still not working, converting them to anonymous. "on new {ti.IngresosParciales} equals new {TI = ip.TotalIngresos}"